# How to save the id passed in the route in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, laravel-validation

I need to save the id passed in the route to the database on my store function which has a seperate function to validate,

Here's my web route

```
   Route::resource('venues/{venue}/categories/{category}/sub-categories', 'Manage\SubCategoriesController');
```

Here's my `store` function

```
  public function store($venue, $category, SubCategory $subCategory)
    {
        $subCategory->create($this->validateRequest());
        dd('created');
    }
```

Here's my validate function

```
 // ! Validation
private function validateRequest()
{
    return request()->validate([
    'name'=>'required',
    'discount'=>'sometimes',
    'position'=>'required',
    'special_start'=>'sometimes',
    'special_end'=>'sometimes',
    'category_id'=>'sometimes',
    'venue_id'=>'sometimes'
    ]);
}
```

I need to get the `category_id` and `venue_id` from the route url and save it to the database

**I tried to do this in the validate function but it throws an error**

```
 // ! Validation
private function validateRequest($venue, $category)
{
    return request()->validate([
    'name'=>'required',
    'discount'=>'sometimes',
    'position'=>'required',
    'special_start'=>'sometimes',
    'special_end'=>'sometimes',
    'category_id'=>$venue,
    'venue_id'=>$category
    ]);
}
```

**Store function**

```
     public function store($venue, $category, SubCategory $subCategory)
    {
        $subCategory->create($this->validateRequest($venue, $category));
        dd('created');
    }
```

Can someone suggest me a solution for this problem please

Comment: have you checked `dd($request->all()` all data is coming or not ?

Comment: That `resource` definition name should be `Route::resource('venues.categories.sub-categories', ...)` ... and validation works off of rules not values

Comment: `Route::resource('one.two', 'TestController');` it will gives `http://127.0.0.1:8000/one/{one_id}/two/{two_id}`

Comment: `'category_id'=>$venue, 'venue_id'=>$category` Looks like you got those mixed up?!

Comment: what are you actually trying to validate for `category_id` and `venue_id` via the inputs?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work is because the route parameters `$venue` and `$category` are not part of the request data.

You need to either send them as part of your request, or merge them with your request data like bellow:

```
public function store($venue, $category, SubCategory $subCategory)
{
    request()->merge([
      'venue_id' => $venue,
      'category_id' => $category,
    ]);
    
    $subCategory->create($this->validateRequest());
}
```

Comment: I tried the the above merge, it does not get's the id's 
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'venue_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `sub_categories` (`name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Alexis Michael, 2020-11-20 12:46:26, 2020-11-20 12:46:26))

Comment: @Jareer are the `venue_id` and `category_id` fields "fillable" on the model?

Comment: Its working now, after i added venue_id and category_id fields to fillable   @cDruc

Answer (score 0):

I had to pass the `category_id` and the `venue_id` to the `create.blade.php` view into hidden inputs,

Create function

```
  public function create($venue, $category)
    {
        $data = [
            'category'=>$category,
            'venue'=>$venue,
        ];

        return view('manage.subcategories.create')->with($data);
    }
```

Create Blade

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $venue }}" name='venue_id'>
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $category }}" name='category_id'>
```

Now when i `dd($request->all());` it gets `category_id` and the `venue_id`

Out Put

[image]

Now i can save it using the validation

```
 public function store(Request $request, $venue, $category, SubCategory $subCategory)
    {
        // dd($request->all);
        $subCategory->create($this->validateRequest($venue, $category));
        dd('created');
    }
```